# Firebase - verify session cookie or idtoken

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I've got an api where I validate an `idToken` from firebase, this api is used by a web app and a mobile app.

The web app uses a `session token` and the mobile app the standard `idToken`.

As it stands my api correctly validates the standard token from the mobile app using the admin sdk's `admin.auth().verifyIdToken()` method.

If I pass the session token to this it fails with an iss error

`Firebase ID token has incorrect "iss" (issuer) claim`

I know I can validate the session token via
`admin.auth().verifySessionCookie()` method. But I would have to do this in the `catch` block of the `verifyIdToken` promise.

Is there a method or way where I can just use one step to validate this token, or is my only option to catch an error from one and then try the other method?

Comment: 1. can you please specify the fireabase version you are currently using? and why do you need the session token for?

Comment: The session token is needed for the web application as it also does some server side work. As for the version I’m not sure, it should be the latest stable release

Comment: Why do you pass both tokens to your backend? Normally you would use one or the other depend on your app/website architecture.

Comment: I do only post one at a time, my point is that depending on what is communicating with the backend it sends a different type of token e.g app or website. I therefore either need extra checks to then determine what verify method to call, or I need to call both to see if either one is successful. My question is therefore if there is a single/simpler way to do this. My current investigation seems like there is not and I either need to pass an additional identifier to determine what to call, or I just call both and only respond with an error if both error

Comment: Why not just use session cookie on both platform as the cookie will eventually be sent with requests on mobile devices too?